# Unable to share entire screen in google meet in Brave on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, google, sharing, brave, google-hangouts

I am using Brave `Version 1.45.131 Chromium: 107.0.5304.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)` on `Ubuntu 22.04` and when I try to share the entire screen in google meet, a complete black screen is shared. Please refer the following screenshot
[image: Black screen when sharing]

Please find permissions granted for google meet as follows,

[image: Permissions]
[image: Permissions]

I have even tried with switching to a new profile as well, but still the issue persists. Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

***Note:***
It does allows me to share by `window` but in it file explorer (Nautilus) and terminal windows are not listed for sharing. And this is same in latest Chrome (Version 107.0.5304.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)) as well.

Comment: How did you install the Brave browser? Snap, flatpak or deb? If it's snap or flatpak you might need to give it permissions to asses the whole screen?

Comment: @Chokoladekiks using the `apt` as instructed in https://brave.com/linux/#release-channel-installation. Also please refer the `note` section I just added

Comment: I made a quick duck search, and found this from braves forum: https://community.brave.com/t/cant-share-screen-in-google-meet/194569
Can you please ensure that you have the Hangouts extension `enabled` in `Settings --> Extensions`?

Comment: @Chokoladekiks it is already enabled and I checked on `Chrome` latest as well. It too has the same issue. Seems like it is a bug in Chromium itself

Comment: I just tested sharing my whole screen on Google Meet, using a firefox browser. Here I had no issue. I did have to give permission. If possible, could you try in firefox aswell, just to determent where the issue might be?

Comment: @Chokoladekiks in firefox it works as expected. So it seems the issue in Chromium isn't it?

Comment: So I install Brave using apt, and tried again. I see the same window to share my screen as in your pic#1. I also see in your pic#1 you haven't selected a screen (1 or 2) to share. Are you able to select a screen on this pop up window?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140928/discussion-between-chokoladekiks-and-kasun-siyambalapitiya).